How to Hide My App Content While My App Is In Background
I am Developing One App With Java And I Want To Hide My App Content While My App Is In Background.
Suppose If User Has Pressed Home Or Recent App Button Then My App Content Should Hide OR Blur OR I Want To set Secure Screen Which Will Show Different Content.
Whatsapp Has That Feature Already, If App Is In Background Then You're Not Able to see App Contents In The Recent App Section.
enter image description here
If Anyone Has Example Or Suggestion Then Please Do Let Me Know. Thanks.
I Have Tryied Lifecycle Method Whenever My App Is Goes Background State Then I am Redirecting my user to different Screen But That Is Not Working, That Works Only when i came back to my app.

Use FLAG_SECURE.

please do not use capital letter on each word. Apply proper English grammar rules
